core dump encountered when linking against to gperftools
I have a customer library which will be invoked by java through JNI, then I want to do a profiling with that through gperftools, the code is below:
Findgperftools:
include(ExternalProject)

set(GPERFTOOLS_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gperftools-install")

set(GPERFTOOLS_CONFIGURE_ARGS
    "AR=${CMAKE_AR}"
    "RANLIB=${CMAKE_RANLIB}"
    "CC=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}"
    "CXX=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}"
    "--disable-shared"
    "--enable-hidden-visibility"
    "--prefix=${GPERFTOOLS_PREFIX}"
    "CFLAGS=-fPIC"
    "CXXFLAGS=-fPIC")

ExternalProject_Add(
        gperftools
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools.git
        GIT_TAG gperftools-2.15.90
        UPDATE_COMMAND "./autogen.sh"
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./configure --prefix=${GPERFTOOLS_CONFIGURE_ARGS}
        BUILD_COMMAND ""
        BUILD_IN_SOURCE true
        INSTALL_COMMAND $(MAKE) install
        INSTALL_DIR ${GPERFTOOLS_PREFIX}
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(gperftools INSTALL_DIR)

set(GPERFTOOLS_INCLUDE_DIR ${INSTALL_DIR}/include)
message(STATUS "gperftools include dir: ${GPERFTOOLS_INCLUDE_DIR}")

set(GPERFTOOLS_LIBRARY ${INSTALL_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}profiler${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX})
message(STATUS "gperftools static library: ${GPERFTOOLS_LIBRARY}")

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(gperftools DEFAULT_MSG GPERFTOOLS_INCLUDE_DIR GPERFTOOLS_LIBRARY)

set(GPERFTOOLS_LIBRARYS ${GPERFTOOLS_LIBRARY})
set(GPERFTOOLS_INCLUDE_DIRS ${GPERFTOOLS_INCLUDE_DIR})

project CMakeLists.txt:
if(ENABLE_GPERFTOOLS)
  find_package(gperftools)
  if(NOT gperftools_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "gperftools not found!")
  endif()
  add_dependencies(customer_lib gperftools)

  add_definitions(-DENABLE_GPERFTOOLS)
  target_include_directories(customer_lib PRIVATE ${GPERFTOOLS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  target_link_libraries(customer_lib PRIVATE ${GPERFTOOLS_LIBRARYS})
endif()

Source code:
#ifdef ENABLE_GPERFTOOLS
  ProfilerStart("")
#endif

other code

#ifdef ENABLE_GPERFTOOLS
  ProfilerStop()
#endif

I works fine on my laptop(linux), by in the production env, it will core dump like this:
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb5a84ea94f, pid=36567, tid=0x00007fb56d3ff700
#
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgcc_s.so.1+0xf94f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

btw, the core is accidental.
Any suggestions are very appreciated!

Whenever code runs on one machine and not on another machine (or different compilation options) it can be a sign of undefined behavior. Your question is also unclear about a few things, 1) did you write customer_lib, 2) What do you mean by "the core is accidental", do you mean the core dump only happens intermittendly? Next step would be to allow writing of that core dump and start debugging (we can't do that for you)

@PepijnKramer Thanks for your comment. 1) Yes, I wrote the customer_lib, I want evaluate its performance, 2) the customer_lib runs in a distributed application and hundreds of processes will invoke it and some of it will failed.  actually, I can't enable core dump in the production env,  but in the dev enviroment, I can't reproduce it ....  So I want to make sure that I have introduced gperftools into my project in the wrong way.

How many unit tests does your library have and how much code do they cover?  Can you also run your unit tests with gperf build? Side note : I am not familiar with JNI or Java at all.  And what is different in the production environment wrt. dev environment? This can also provide hints on what's going wrong.

Yes, I can run the end-to-end integration testing with gperf build. Most of the software versions in the production environment and the development environment are the same, such as gcc (which I have confirmed), but the kernel version may be different, and the cpu type may be different (but only intel and amd). Will this affect?

That's the pain with subtle bugs (undefined behavior) they may pop up at any time when you change compiler or compiler settings.

Add compile args --enable-frame-pointers can fix this issue, more info please refer to https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/issues/1561
